# A question about the sound channel in the ocean

Tags: waves, acoustics, geophysics

The [sound channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOFAR_channel) (SOFAR channel) in the ocean is about 1000 meters below the surface.

It is said that sound can get trapped in this channel and propagates thousand kilometers without dissipation, and because it is a 2D medium, the strength of the sound decays in the $1/R$ law.

But the question is, why does the trapping help? Even without trapping, the ocean can be considered as a two dimensional medium (as it is very thin compared to its lateral size), and the strength of the sound decays in the 1/R law.

Comment: Are you referring to the thermocline?

Comment: What don't you understand about the explanation included in the first section of the linked Wikipedia article?

Comment: I just want to emphasize that, the ocean is automatically a 2d medium

Comment: Sorry, I read the question on a smart phone and didn't notice the link.